# Access resource files like xml inside jar after deployed on pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar, cloud-foundry

I created one java micro service using spring boot. The application requires some data from static xml files (kept together in a folder, lets name it X) in src/main/resources folder.(I am using STS IDE)
It is working fine when I run it in the IDE itself. 
Now when I pack it in a jar and try running it using CLI (java -jar jarFileName.jar) it works and access the folder X from the target/classes folder.

Now my problem is, when I try to deploy this small app on Pivotal Cloud Foundry using either CLI or STS plugin, I have to give a path to the jar file so it uploads only the respective jar file and starts the container with the application. **But the application cannot access folder X which contains its resources**.

Though I confirmed that the jar file contains the folder X in BOOT-INF/classes but it tries to find the folder X on its own path - not inside itself.

Does anyone have some idea how can a jar file deployed on PCF can access its resources kept inside itself.

I tried using

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("X/abc.xml")
```

but it didn't work. It is unable to find the path during runtime.

Comment: What you are asking is an anti-pattern for cloud native development. 
Please check out https://12factor.net/

Comment: Try to use something like [Spring Cloud Config Server](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html)

Comment: At runtime you want to load your xml file then please check out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

why do not try Apache Abdera.
your XML is obtained from an API.

just another way, btw.

Answer (score 0):

In your main class(usually Application.java) add `@ImportResource` annotation at class level.
Example: `@ImportResource("classpath:myfile.xml")`